# read music from musiclibrary

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

How can i read music(sound) from music library(sound library)?(like apps that read music from music library for set alarm for alarm clock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is very good example in the sample code how to reach media library

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: add 'window.rootViewController = mainViewController;' in applicationDidFinishLaunching to be able to compile